# <select> tag doesn't keep background color on iphone

Tags: ios, css, select, dropdown

So, basically, I can change the background color of a  tag on my computer but when I open the website through and iPhone (doesn't matter if I'm using Safari or Chrome) the background color is that default gradient gray.

I also tried to do it through the javascript, didn't work.

NOTE: i am NOT talking about the menu, only about the box we see without the options below, the one that if we click it shows the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue before. 
Does the background have a opacity?

for example:

```
    background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.543):
```

If that is the case remove the opacity. In this case it would be the 0.543

Comment: Actually it doesn't D: So that's not the issue.